# Utilizing GPU fails with tensorflow and CUDA with process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I try to use my GPU for the first time to run a model with Tensorflow it exits whenever training starts with message:

```
Epoch 1/15
2022-05-07 00:46:23.749793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8303

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

My setup:

GTX 1650

tensorflow 2.7.0

CUDA 11.5

cudNN 8.3.3

Python 3.8.0

Here is the model and the preprocessing:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './horse-or-human/',  # This is the source directory for training images
    target_size=(150, 150),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=128,
    # Since you used binary_crossentropy loss, you need binary labels
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './validation-horse-or-human/',  # This is the source directory for training images
    target_size=(150, 150),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=32,
    # Since you used binary_crossentropy loss, you need binary labels
    class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=8,
    epochs=15,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=8)
```

Comment: What is your batch size and input image size? Do you have data augmentations? It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproduction.

Comment: I have edited the question to include rest of the code
batch size is 128, image size is (150,150)

Comment: What is the size of the source image? Could you try to reduce the batch size to 2, and then try again?

Comment: source image is 300,300 
I tried to change batch size to 2 but same problem

Comment: This problem arises due to CUDA, cuDNN not synced with the NVIDIA driver properly. Please follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) link to configure your Windows machine to enable GPU support.

Also, Please check [this](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/620#issuecomment-755989786) similar resolved issue for your reference.